# Can't Run Rails Server, Could Not Find Gem 'rails(4.2.5.1) x86-mingw32'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to learn Ruby on Rails. Currently been trying out Rails framework. I've installed it. Create new project, but when I try to run:

rails server

I get back an error:

Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.2.5.1) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. 
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I've installed bundle as suggested. Had few problems with installing it as well, but I've found a soultion on the internet.

Before bundle install I was getting another error saying that
could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>=0) x86-mingw32'; so i installed this gem:
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw] ; and it worked.

I'm running windows 7, please help, BIG THANKS.

Comment: Looks like an issue with your `$PATH`. Can you post the output of `echo %path%` from your console?

Comment: C:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>echo %path%
C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby
2.1.0\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin;C:\windows\system32;C
:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Mi
crosoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared
\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows
\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows

Comment: Live\Shared;C:\
Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon
\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\AUTO
DE~1\GIS\IMPORT~1\2.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Graitec;C:\Program Fil
es (x86)\Common Files\Graitec\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Graitec\;D:\E20-II\
Enviro;C:\E20-II\Enviro;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Pr
ogram Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Gi
t\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin;C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: I think you should use a Linux distribution, because Ruby on Rails is primary made for Linux. If you are using the installer from railsinstaller.org you should try to use 'gem update'

Comment: gem update didn't work @dthal

Comment: Then try to use a Linux distribution

Comment: what an advice! plz can someone else help

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me. If it is useless please let me know.

`gem install rails -v 4.2.5.1`